# Как перекрыть на странице все эелементы

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css3

Есть родительский элемент с **position: relative** и вложеный c **position: absolute**. Надо перекрыть всё этим вложеным элементом. Когда задаю **z-index**, то этот вложеный элемент ничего не перекрывает. А надо чтобы он перекрывал всех родителей.

Родитель:

```
.lesson{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Ребёнок:

```
.lesson .lesson__tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо перекрыть всё этим чёрным блоком, чтобы его было полностью видно

Comment: Сделай тестовый пример вместо картинки...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задай ребенку:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
z-index: 999;
```